# How to install MySQL DB to a certain partition? (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

Question in a title, how can I install MySQL DB to a certain partition in a Linux (Ubuntu)? I don't want to move my DB after installing, I want to install it certain partition at once

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By default, MySQL (and MariaDB) stores database files in `/var/lib/mysql`. The Data Directory is controlled by the `--datadir` option in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. So you can edit your config file and set an alternative location using the `datadir` option:

```
datadir=/new/partition
```

Alternatively, you could setup a new partition specifically for the default location of `/var/lib/mysql` when you go to install the operating system. So you would create a separate partition specifically for the MySQL directory. Then in your `/etc/fstab` file, you'd add the new partition and point it to `/var/lib/mysql`. For example, if you have 1 partition now, and 1 swap partition, you'd add the 3rd partition, and your `fstab` file might look like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/sda       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sdb                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdc       /var/lib/mysql   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0      1
```

See the following for a few resources:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_datadir and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-move-a-mysql-data-directory-to-a-new-location-on-ubuntu-16-04